# What is the argument being passed to `np.ones` and how does it work here?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I actually wanted to multiply the array into 3 and tried to use * 3 inside the shape. I then realized it has to be outside the np.ones like `np.ones((1,2))*4`. But was wondering why this is producing exponential results. Can someone please explain to me the below behavior?

`np.ones((1,2)*1)` returns `array([[1., 1.]])`

`np.ones((1,2)*2)` returns

```
array([[[[1., 1.]],
        [[1., 1.]]]])
```

`np.ones((1,2)*3)` returns

```
array([[[[[[1., 1.]],
          [[1., 1.]]]],
        [[[[1., 1.]],
          [[1., 1.]]]]]])
```

Similarly, `np.ones((1,2)*4)` returns

```
array([[[[[[[[1., 1.]],
            [[1., 1.]]]],
          [[[[1., 1.]],
            [[1., 1.]]]]]],
        [[[[[[1., 1.]],
            [[1., 1.]]]],
          [[[[1., 1.]],
            [[1., 1.]]]]]]]])
```

Unfortunately, the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ones.html) doesn't have any explanation on this.

Comment: You're accidentally applying the multiplication operator on the tuples, then passing those to `np.ones`.

Comment: Run `(1, 2) * 3` in a python REPL and see what happens. Then pass that result to `np.ones` and see what happens again. A little experimentation is all you'd have to do.

Comment: `(1,2)*3` makes it `(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)` but `np.ones((1,2)*3)` gives `array([[[[[[1., 1.]],
          [[1., 1.]]]],
        [[[[1., 1.]],
          [[1., 1.]]]]]])`

Comment: And what is `np.ones((1,2)*3).shape`?

Comment: same as `(1,2)*3`. Interesting. Can you please explain the funda?

Comment: `np.ones` accepts a "shape" parameter and returns an N-D array according to the shape. If you specify `np.ones((10,))` you get a 1D array with 10 elements... `np.ones((3, 5))` will give you a 2D array of size 3x5 with 3*5=15 elements,... and so on. You get the idea.

Comment: Cool. Would you mind adding this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.ones` accepts a `shape` parameter and returns an N-D array according to your specification. For example, with `np.ones((10,))`, you get a 1D array with 10 elements... `np.ones((3, 5))` will give you a 2D array of size 3x5 with 3*5=15 elements,... and so on.

Now, you've done (for example) `(1, 2) * 3`, which if you run in a python REPL will show

```
(1, 2) * 3
# (1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)
```

Passing this to `np.ones` will return a 6D array of shape  `(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)` with 8 elements.

```
np.ones((1, 2)*3)     
array([[[[[[1., 1.]],    
          [[1., 1.]]]],
        [[[[1., 1.]],    
          [[1., 1.]]]]]])

_.shape
# (1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)
```

And similar, for the others.